# How to debug this information in swift (SIGTRAP #0 )?

Tags: swift, swift2

My application crashed, and I don't know the problem..

```
0   klood                               0x00000001000e4640 0x1000ac000 + 230976
1   PexKit                              0x00000001003a17e8 0x100334000 + 448488
2   PexKit                              0x00000001003a1414 0x100334000 + 447508
3   Foundation                          0x0000000182f04540 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 16
4   Foundation                          0x0000000182e56870 -[NSBlockOperation main] + 96
5   Foundation                          0x0000000182e46e48 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 604
6   Foundation                          0x0000000182f06934 __NSOQSchedule_f + 224
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000181f9547c _dispatch_client_callout + 16
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000181f9ab84 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1844
9   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182500d50 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
10  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001824febb8 __CFRunLoopRun + 1628
11  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000182428c50 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
12  GraphicsServices                    0x0000000183d10088 GSEventRunModal + 180
13  UIKit                               0x0000000187712088 UIApplicationMain + 204
14  klood                               0x0000000100162fb0 0x1000ac000 + 749488
15  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000181fc68b8 start + 4
```

I think the problem maybe is `_dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF`, and I don't know how to fix it, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the beginning, follow your code step by step with breakpoints. If you don't know where to start, place your breakpoint at the first viewDidLoad() and just follow from there.

Comment: It happens not all the time, and it not me to find that, it others find that, can you give me some informaitons from my informations

Comment: If other people encounter this, the best thing you can do is to ask them for their exact steps (which screen, which button). Sorry I can't help better. Maybe someone else could decypher your error lines.